# Why does jQuery require you to prefix a # in front of id selectors?

Tags: jquery, html

As the question states, why do we need to use $( "#id" ) rather than just simply $( id )?

Comment: `$( id )` -- is it a variable that you're passing? Did you intentionally drop the quote characters?

Comment: because jQuery  basically uses css selectors, if a variable contains selector strings it can be used also

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are an implementation of most of the [CSS selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) with a couple of extensions of its own.

Syntax without the `#` already has a meaning, it represents a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors), not an [id selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors).

Syntax without the quotes would be a [JavaScript variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables) instead of a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#String_literals) (something entirely outside the control of jQuery). You can, of course, us an identifier to access a variable containing a string.

Answer (score 0):

because the `#` means that you are pointing to an id, you can also use `.` to classes

[Full Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's selection engine is based on [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is a "pure-Javascript CSS selector engine." It is based on css selectors, so the # is included for ideas.

Sizzle requires strings to be passed to it, so `$( id )` is not valid unless `id` is a variable with a string value.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors are based on CSS selectors. The selector needs to evaluate to a string.

In your example $( id ). You're passing in a variable called id. This won't find something called 'id' but it will look for the string value of id.

$('p') would select all p elements
$('#myid') would select the element with the id myid
$('.myclass') would select the element with the class myclass

This is quite well documented.
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/